# Google Translator not working with sumome

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-translate

I have attached the Google translator widget in a site but today I just see that its not working in Firefox, and Safari. Google translator drop down hide on hover. But when I remove or replace [sumome](https://sumome.com/)
code with another [sumome](https://sumome.com/) account it works fine.
I have checked the flash player it is up to date.
any one has some clue why it is happening?

Comment: Perhaps your account ran out of free requests. Look in the console

Comment: There is no error or warning being shown in the console